# AJAX return JSON filtered response with callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I feel like im close, i need to return my filtered json object data and be able to use it in future functions. My main issue im having is its saying "callback is not a function". I used the second method in the top response here [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call?noredirect=1&lq=1) 
Thanks!

```
function randomFxn(callback){
  var newObj = {};
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/album/' + imgurID + '/images',
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Client-ID '+ key},
    success: function(jsonData){
      var nameArr = ['mario', 'luigi', "...some other stuff"];
      var counter = 0;
      var inCounter = 0;

      for(var i = 0; i < nameArr.length; i++){
        for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++){
          newObj[nameArr[counter]+j] = jsonData.data[inCounter].link;
        }
        counter++;
      }

      // $('body').html(`<pre>${JSON.stringify(newObj, null, '\t')}</pre>`);
      console.log(newObj);
      callback(newObj);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: what is the `callback`? where is it defined????

Comment: Show us how you call `randomFxn()`. Seems you are not passing a function argument when you call it

Comment: Ok so im still not super understanding this, so i may have made a dumb mistake. But i want newObj to be called back, so i can basically store it in a global variable and use that data whenever i want.

Comment: randomFxn(); randomFxn(finalJsonArr); and finalJsonArr = random(); is how i called it, finalJsonArr being an empty object i defined near the start. But it only says that callback is not a function, i assumine from callback(newObj)

Comment: @webdeb That gave me this, http://prntscr.com/flctwt. Which is great, but can i store that result in a global variable?

Comment: you can assign it to the `window` 

`randomFxn(function(res) { window.res = res })`

Comment: Just some code commentary... save yourself a lot of hassle and use Promises.  They're built in with your AJAX call, and you can do some filtering.  Then, look into map or reduce for the response filtering.  For what it's worth, what you're doing to the response seems crazy to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, you have to call `randomFxn` like so:

```
randomFxn(function(result) {
  console.log("got result", result);
});
```

Comment: My main objective is to have the JSON stored in a global object variable, if possible, using callbacks, so that i can use it like any other variable, viewing it is not my issue atm.

Comment: @Fullmetal7777 you can assign it to global variable, but it will be filled only after you async request is finished.

Comment: ive tried that, and it always comes back undefined because of the whole asynchronicity aspect

Comment: So what is the point of a callback then? I figured the main reason was so that you could store JSON data in a global variable?

Comment: @Fullmetal7777 it all depends on you application, but you'll have to deal with async anyway.

Comment: gotcha, so ill just have to keep calling it as a function as wayne allen described then?

Comment: I would't put the business logic inside the ajax call, the way with the callback is more general, you can perform your business logic there, so you have a better overview of your code.

Comment: thats a good idea, itl make it way more efficient that way. Thanks for all your help, i really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

The error is not in this function - it is how you are calling this function.

There are two ways to fix the problem, depending upon the logic of your application.  You could change your function to this:

```
function randomFxn(){
  var newObj = {};
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/album/' + imgurID + '/images',
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Client-ID '+ key},
    success: function(jsonData){
      var nameArr = ['mario', 'luigi', "...some other stuff"];
      var counter = 0;
      var inCounter = 0;

      for(var i = 0; i < nameArr.length; i++){
        for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++){
          newObj[nameArr[counter]+j] = jsonData.data[inCounter].link;
        }
        counter++;
      }

      // $('body').html(`<pre>${JSON.stringify(newObj, null, '\t')}</pre>`);
      console.log(newObj);
    }
  });
}
```

Or, wherever you call `randomFxn`, you need to pass another function as a parameter:

```
randomFxn(function() {
    // do something here
});
```